# Cross referencing two tables in python?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `article`. It has a column `article.id` and `article.snippet`.

I have another table called `article_vote`. It has a column `article_id` (which is a foreign key for `article.id`) and `vote_choice_id` (which is a number from 1 to 6).

I want to plug a snippet in and have the program count all the `vote_choice_id`’s for that snippet when the vote_choice_id = 1, vote_choice_id = 2, vote_choice_id = 3, etc. That means cross-referencing these two tables, which confuses me.

Here's my current code:

```
##############################################
class Article(db.Model):
    # object mirrors table 'article'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(400))
    url = db.Column(db.String(400))
    image_url = db.Column(db.String(400))
    snippet = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    date_upload = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, title, url, image_url, snippet):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.image_url = image_url
        self.snippet = snippet


##############################################
class ArticleVote(db.Model):
    # object mirrors table 'article_vote'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.fb_id'))  # Sloppy
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'))
    vote_choice_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(400))

    def __init__(self, user_id, article_id, vote_choice_id, comment):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.article_id = article_id
        self.vote_choice_id = vote_choice_id
        self.comment = comment
```

And then here's what I wrote after I tried to follow an example that I couldn't quite understand:

```
##############################################
class PublicationVoteSummary():
# This object keeps the count of votes for a Publication

    def __init__(self, article_id):
        self.snippet = snippet
        self.choice_count = {}  # count by textual choice
        self.choice_id = {}

        pub_choice_list = VoteChoice.getVoteChoiceList()

        for item in pub_choice_list:
            self.choice_id[str(item.id)] = item.choice
        for item in pub_choice_list:
            self.choice_count[item.choice] = 0
        self.total_votes = 0

    def addVote(self, choice):
        self.choice_count[choice] = self.choice_count[choice] + 1
        self.total_votes = self.total_votes + 1

    def getVoteCount(self, choice):
        return self.choice_count[choice]

##############################################
def retrieve_publication_summary(article_id):
    pub_obj = PublicationSummary(article_id)
    publication_list = db.session.query(ArticleVote, Snippet).filter(ArticleVote.article_id == article_id).filter(
        ArticleVote.vote_choice_id == 1).all()
   for item in vote_choice_id:
        # avs_obj.appendComment(item.comment) # 09/27 - added to show comments in results page
        avs_obj.appendDetail((item[1].name, text, item[0].comment))  
    return pub_obj
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT 1.(count)
FROM   article_vote
       INNER JOIN vote_choice_id
           ON Article.id = Article_vote.article_id
WHERE  Article_vote.vote_choice_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will output the `snippet` and count of votes for each `vote_choice_id` for that snippet (as long as there at least one `vote_choice_id` for a given snippet).

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

q = (db.session.query(Article.snippet, ArticleVote.vote_choice_id, sa.func.count(ArticleVote.id))
              .join(ArticleVote, Article.id == ArticleVote.article_id)
              .group_by(Article.snippet, ArticleVote.vote_choice_id)
              .order_by(Article.snippet, ArticleVote.vote_choice_id.desc()))

for snippet, vote_choice_id, count in q:
    print(snippet, vote_choice_id, count)
```

The code generates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT article.snippet AS article_snippet, article_vote.vote_choice_id AS article_vote_vote_choice_id, count(article_vote.id) AS count_1 
FROM article 
JOIN article_vote ON article.id = article_vote.article_id 
GROUP BY article.snippet, article_vote.vote_choice_id 
ORDER BY article.snippet, article_vote.vote_choice_id DESC
```

And produces output like

```
New York Times 6 38
New York Times 5 46
New York Times 4 36
New York Times 3 44
New York Times 2 34
...
```

To get the count for a given `snippet` and `vote_choice_id` can be obtained by adding filters to the query (and removing `vote_choice_id` from the output, and the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses):

```
q = (db.session.query(Article.snippet, sa.func.count(ArticleVote.id))
               .join(ArticleVote, Article.id == ArticleVote.article_id)
               .filter(Article.snippet == 'New York Times')
               .filter(ArticleVote.vote_choice_id == 2)
               .group_by(Article.snippet))
for snippet, count in q:
    print(snippet, count)
```

Generating this SQL:

```sql
SELECT article.snippet AS article_snippet, count(article_vote.id) AS count_1 
FROM article 
JOIN article_vote ON article.id = article_vote.article_id 
WHERE article.snippet = ? AND article_vote.vote_choice_id = ?
```

and this output:

```
New York Times 34
```

Comment: Hi there. I'm actually trying to get the votes for all articles with the same "snippet," (snippet is my word for publication — like nytimes.com) not just the votes for that particular article. This just seems to pull all the vote for that particular article, not all the articles with the same publication. That's why I'm trying to cross-reference the Article table.

Comment: I've changed the query - does it do what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, this has been messing with me for days.

Comment: If you have a chance: Do you know how I would store counts for different vote choices as different variables? Like a variable for the count of all the 2s, a different variable for the count of all the 3s, etc?

Comment: I don't think you could easily get them all in a single row - I'd suggest modifying the first query, forr example adding `.filter(ArticleVote.vote_choice_id == 2)` between the `.join` and the `.group_by`, which would give you one row per snippet/choice combination.

Comment: One more question --- for some snippets, there are no votes. In those situations, nothing prints. I want it to print 0. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There _might_ be a way to do that, but if there is it would require more SQL skill than I possess.  You'd be better of asking a new question I think.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, asking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686624/how-to-make-null-none-count-0-instead?noredirect=1#comment109117386_61686624